# how to i get my code to loop to the input after getting the first input?

Tags: python, input

**this is my code**:

```
a = input("Enter word here: ")
print("Reverse is", a[::-1])
```

**this is my result**:

```
Enter word here: patronus
Reverse is sunortap
```

**this is what I want**:

```
Enter word here: patronus
Reverse is sunortap
Enter word here:
```

I want it to ask for new words 10 times before it terminates.

Comment: Put the code inside a `for _ in range(10):` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(10):
    a = input("Enter word here: ")
    print("Reverse is", a[::-1])
```

This works by looping 10 times. You can test it by printing i within the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(10):
  a = input("Enter word here: ")
  print("Reverse is", a[::-1])
```